# What's the purpose of CSS box model? Is it necessary to learn?

Tags: html, css

I've been learning web development for the past couple of days through YouTube.so there's a video a YouTuber made on CSS box model.does it have a purpose in making webpages? I don't know what is its purpose in making webpages..so is it necessary for one to learn it?

Comment: Necessary? No. Helpful? Potentially, it depends on you. If you design web pages, then you'll end up picking it up either way.

Comment: The box model is quite important in CSS, yes. Until you understand it, you probably won’t get very far with layouting in CSS. But this is not the kind of question you should be asking here to begin with.

Comment: The box model is the basic building block of all web page layouts. You should learn it before anything else in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I'd say if you're into frontend programming, you won't get around the box model. But it's not very complicated either, I can highly recommend this entry to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model